# Design coil for rfid chip

Tags: antenna, inductance, rfid, coil

I broke an rfid coil which is soldered to a chip. I want to build the coil as it will save me the pain of replacing the chip as it's not something you can find easily.

The coil itself was quite small. It's broken so I cannot measure it but I would guess the diameter of the insulator was about 1mm and the length of the antenna was about 5 mm. The wire thickness I measured about 0.02mm. Now I know this is a very small coil, but I need to create one which shouldn't be a problem as long as I get the right wire.

I cannot find online the relationship between the frequency and the inductance of the coil although I am assuming it is probably the frequency value used to calculate the impedance. The frequency I am aiming for is 433.92 MHz.

Who can point me in the right direction? I have found a tool to calculate the loops and type of wire based on the inductance value.

Comment: What do you mean? I edited to add information.

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: Did you do an on-line search for "RFID antenna"?

Comment: I did but everything talks about the 130kHz frequency antenna. Nothing too general about making an antenna for a specific frequency. Plus it's a coil not a simple antenna. I just updated the description. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: If you can identify the chip, the data sheet will have the antenna specifications and detailed design information.

Comment: [Antenna Circuit Design for RFID Applications](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00710c.pdf)